# How to set analytics goal for urls consisting of dynamically generated numbers in the url stub?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have the url as shown below

http://www.somesite.com/icons/898989898998?download=1

I need to configure this url for the goal to find how many hits for this url. Kindly help me out in this.

I tried configuring /icons/\d*?download=1 with regular expression but it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to *escape* the `?`

this matches `898989898998`:

```
/icons/\d*\?download=1
```